# Divide single table into 2 table in mobile view with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a single table in desktop. Client wants its to be shown as 2 tables in mobile view. Is there a way to achieve it without duplication of html or should I take div method instead of table?

**Desktop view:**

[image]

**Mobile view:**

[image]

Comment: What you could do, is to divide your table in 2, but you stick them in large screen (`col-lg-6` for each), and give them `col-xs-12` for each.

Answer (score 1):

you can use 2 table together like this

pic

[image: table]

code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
        .tb_1{
            float:left;
            width:50%;
        }
        .tb_2{
            float:Right;
            width:50%;
        }
        @media only screen and (max-width: 619px) {
            .tb_1{width:100%;}
            .tb_2{width:100%;}
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table class="tb_1" border="1">
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>6</td>
            <td>7</td>
            <td>8</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table class="tb_2" border="1">
        <tr>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>9</td>
            <td>10</td>
        </tr
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```